Does Elden Ring lock you into “battle” animations?
Does elden ring lock you into attack/heal/spell animations? That is, can you roll while in one to cancel the animation and avoid a hit, or will you be forced to complete the animation?
Are there any other “battle” animations you’re locked into/can dodge out of?

“Battle” animations are to be defined as any animation that are most likely to be done in battle, such as using a weapon, casting a spell or incantation, buffing, drinking a flask, rolling, jumping (exception to the rule), or other similar actions.

Yes, you are "locked in."  Specifically, Elden Ring uses "input queuing", a.k.a. "input buffering": If you press a button to take an action while the animation for a previous action is still on-going, the current action/animation will run to completion, and then after that your character will perform the new action.
